# Connection checking in React causes a hook order change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to setup a React app where a verification of the credentials is performed on each page. Around each page, I already had a wrapper that sets the title of the page, so I thought this might be the best place. This works well 90% of the time, but I recently tried to use the `useNagivate` hook and now all hell goes loose. In particular, I'm trying to use the hook to go from one page to another with a state carried over.

Traditional navigation works perfectly fine (with redirection if not connected as I would like), but using the `useNavigate` hook seem to break things.

Here is the code for the `TitleSetter` wrapper I mentioned.

```
import { Suspense } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginPage, { isConnected } from "../pages/login";

type TitleSetterProps = { title: string, element: () => JSX.Element }

function fetchConnectionStatus() {
 let status = "pending";
 let result: Error | boolean;
 let suspender = isConnected().then(
   r => {
     status = "success";
     result = r;
   },
   e => {
     status = "error";
     result = e;
   }
 );
 return {
   read() {
     if (status === "pending") throw suspender;
     else if (status === "error") throw result;
     else if (status === "success") return result;
   },
 };
};

const connectionStatusFetch = fetchConnectionStatus();

export default function TitleSetter({ title, element }: TitleSetterProps) {
  document.title = title;

  return <Suspense fallback={<>Checking connection status...</>}>
    <ConnectionChecker component={element} />
  </Suspense>
}

function ConnectionChecker({ component }: { component: () => JSX.Element }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const connectionStatus = connectionStatusFetch.read()
  const displayComponent = connectionStatus || component === LoginPage
  if (!displayComponent) navigate("/login")

  return component()
}
```

And here is the error:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2655 Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by ConnectionChecker. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useContext                 useContext
2. useContext                 useContext
3. useContext                 useContext
4. useContext                 useContext
5. useContext                 useContext
6. useRef                     useRef
7. useEffect                  useEffect
8. useCallback                useCallback
9. useEffect                  useState
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    at ConnectionChecker (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5212:5)
    at Suspense
    at TitleSetter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5185:5)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:345635:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:346084:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:346015:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:344236:5)
```

The thing is: I don't see where this `useState` hook comes from... Does it come from `component()` ? By the way, I read somewhere that calling a component this way is a bad idea, but the alternatives didn't work for me. It may be part of the problem but not sure. (As you might guess, I'm kinda lost here, I was put in charge of this project without much experience in web, so I'm piecing in things as I go)

If any information is missing, I'll gladly edit my question to make it more complete.

Comment: What is `component` function?

Comment: it's a function that has the type `() => JSX.Element`, more concretely, it's the component that will be displayed as a page of the app

Comment: Maybe you should try making the function a react element and then returning <Component /> to find out if the hook problem is in the component function